# How to mock a method of an imported instance

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I am writing unit test for some python modules. However, I cannot work out a way to mock a method of an imported instance. Below is the python modules that I want to test.

--bar.py--

```
class A():
    @classmethod
    def method_1(self):
        ...    
a = A()
```

--foo.py--

```
from bar import a
class B():
    @classmethod
    def b(cls):
        if a.method_1():
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

--test_foo.py--

```
from foo import B

class TestB(TestCase):
    @patch('foo.a.method_1')
    def test_b(self, mock_method_1):
          mock_method_1.return_value = True
          test_b = B.b()
          ...
```

This does not work. My test case is still calling original `method_1` instead of the one I mocked.

Comment: I forgot to add the `@classmethod` to `method_1` in `class A` at first time. So now I updated the post.

Comment: I tested your case in my desktop, seems it works as expected. What Python version are you using? Perhaps the `mock` package version?

Comment: python==2.7, mock==2.0.0 . What's yours?

Comment: strange. Same here with `python==2.7.12` and `mock==2.0.0`. 
I make `a.method_1()` returns `False`, and  `assert test_b == True` . And the test case passes, which means it calls mocked method.

Comment: Did you try the above example as in your question? Or are you working with your origin-complete codebase? Maybe I'm missing something. But here is something you can try: in `test_foo.py`, instead of using `from foo import B`, use `import foo` and `foo.B()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`patch.object` decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-object) instead. It patches an object's attributes instead of patching a global method.

If that doesn't work, try patching `bar.a` instead of `foo.a`, but I don't think that's your problem here.

### Update

The question changed to a class method, so I think this will work:

--test_foo.py--

```
from foo import B

class TestB(TestCase):
    @patch('bar.A.method_1')
    def test_b(self, mock_method_1):
          mock_method_1.return_value = True
          test_b = B.b()
          ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about `patch.object`. But I think that the only difference between `patch.object` and `patch` is that `patch.object` allows you to use an imported stuff instead of writing the full path. I have tried it anyway but it still didn't work.

Comment: Yes, patching `bar.a` does not help either. :( But thanks still for your help.

Comment: @MarineLu, I updated the answer to match your updated question.